# RoR Prawn PDF back of sheet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, prawn

I want to be able to put a default back of sheet on my generated PDF,
has someone already did this ?

I was wondering if there is something in Prawn to do that, something like an event which is triggered when a new page has been started ?

I made many search about this and cannot see any way to do it, your help will be precious.

Here some code to show you the way I generate my PDF :

```
Prawn::Document.generate(invoice_file, :print_scaling => :none, :top_margin => margin_top) do |pdf|
        pdf.font_size=11
        pdf.define_grid(:columns => 12,:rows => 16, :gutter => 10)
        pdf.font "Helvetica"

        #some code to fill my pdf

        #And what I was trying to deal with it : 
        pdf.repeat(:all, :dynamic => true) do
            pdf.start_new_page
            #some code to fill my new page
        end
 end
```

This is almost working, I get the new created page but it's generating another blank page that I don't need, because of the new one I think. If someone has an idea, I take !

Thanks ! Flo.

Comment: Could you show the code you are currently using?

Comment: @MattGibson Hi, thanks for your reply, I can give you some code but I'm not sure about the help this could bring.

Comment: @MattGibson Updated

Comment: Do you mean something like a background layer? Maybe the [`combine_pdf` gem](https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf) might help?